# QT bluetooth .so integration into Android Java project. Issue with QAndroidJniObject and QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent

Tags: java, android, qt, bluetooth, java-native-interface

**Hello everyone!**

I am writing the code to make able to get android Bluetooth connection via QT library using JNI.
The main idea is to have a black box that connects to devices to get data, analyze and so on, that is why I need to use QT Bluetooth and do not pass device data from java code to lib.

So.

At first, I used JNIEnv* env to check if I can get a Bluetooth adapter, and it works.
Then I used QAndroidJniEnvironment and also got Bluetooth adapter name. Look at the code, please.

```
  static jclass jniMathClassID = 0;
  static jmethodID jniMathConstructorMethodID = 0;
  static jmethodID jniMathElevenMethodID = 0;

  QAndroidJniEnvironment qjniEnv;

  jclass classBta = qjniEnv->FindClass("android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter");

  jmethodID methodIdGetAdapter =
                qjniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(classBta,
                                       "getDefaultAdapter",
                                       "()Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter;");
  jmethodID methodIdGetName =
                qjniEnv->GetMethodID(classBta,
                                 "getName",
                                 "()Ljava/lang/String;");

  jobject objBta = (jobject) qjniEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(classBta, methodIdGetAdapter);

  jstring strName = (jstring) qjniEnv->CallObjectMethod(objBta, methodIdGetName);

  const char *result = qjniEnv->GetStringUTFChars(strName, 0);
  qDebug() << result;
```

So, here I can see the real device Bluetooth adapter name which was received via QAndroidJniEnvironment.

The issue happens when I want to use QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent. I got a message: qt.bluetooth.android: Device does not support Bluetooth

I have looked at the "qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent_android.cpp" file and saw that in the constructor it uses QAndroidJniObject.

```
 QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
    adapter = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter",
                                                        "getDefaultAdapter",
                                                        "()Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter;");
```

and it has nothing in the adapter variable, but if I call that QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod in my own method and change "android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter" to classBta (which you saw above) It works ok.

```
  QAndroidJniObject adapter=QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
      classBta,"getDefaultAdapter","()Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter;");
```

It looks like the QAndroidJniObject works incorrectly and calls the wrong method. 
Could you please help me with this? I really need to make **QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent** work.

Comment: I have got just one guess. When QT creator is being used it looks for android resources in  ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR=$$PWD/android. But I don't use QT creator to create my Android app, I only create .so lib and then use it in Android Studio with JNI calls. So when I pass classBta object as an object (which you saw above), the callStaticObjectMethod works ok, but with the class name android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter it can not find it.... Any thoughts?